# Does Rutgers University Provide Open-Source Geospatial Datasets?

Tags: releasing-data

Might these datasets include business names, addresses (some goecoords), County, CBSA, NAIC, SIC, USPS Postal Carrier route and more information for United States and Canada?.

Answer (score 1):

Why yes, Rutgers University does.

Rutgers University has made available "as-is" Geospatial datasets "that cannot be sold or used in any way for commercial purposes."

http://www.rutgerscps.org/data.html

There datasets cover the US and selected areas in Canada. The data includes business names, addresses (some goecoords), County, CBSA, NAIC, SIC, USPS Postal Carrier route and more.

Rutgers' Disclaimer:
"This data was purchased by Rutgers, The State University of New Jersey, from InfoGroup, for research and educational purposes. It is provided here through the Rutgers Center on Public Security (RCPS) "as is," without any warranty whatsoever, including but not limited to any warranty as to fitness for any particular purpose. The RCPS or its associates, including webinar instructors, make no claims, promises, or guarantees about the accuracy, completeness, or adequacy of the data, and expressly disclaims liability for errors and omissions in its content. It is highly recommended that you personally review the data and/or ground-truth it prior to use. For details, comments, or questions about the data, contact [InfoGroup](http://www.infogroup.com/).

"Permissions: This data, in its current or modified form, must be used for research only. It cannot be sold or used in any way for commercial purposes.

"These datasets are not complete nor comprehensive for the respective geographies. Consider them a list of features to start your collection, then verify the data and build upon it.

"Geography is based on street addresses; XY coordinates in these datasets are not reliable."